# How to stop tkinter thread but keep window open?

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I have a button that when pressed starts a new thread:

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

db = tk.Button(root, text='Download!', height=2, width=30, background='light blue',command=lambda: threading.Thread(target=runYtAction)
          .start()).grid( row=22, column=0, sticky=tk.W, padx=120, pady=(0,10))
```

how do I stop this thread to "cancel" whatever it was doing by clicking a cancel button?

Comment: first you would have to keep thread in variable. You can create thread before you create button and later use `commnad=lambda:variable.start()` or even `command=variable.start` (without `()` and without `lambda`)

Comment: using `db = tk.Button(...).grid()` you assign `None` to `db` because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` always gives `None`. If you want to keep button in variable then you have to do it in two lines `db = tk.Button(...)` and `db.grid()`

Comment: as I know `thread` doesn't have `cancel()` and you would need to create own class for this [python - Is there any way to kill a Thread? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323972/is-there-any-way-to-kill-a-thread). But popular method is to send `queue` to `thread` and it should periodically check if there is message, and use `return` to stop running when it get i.e. string "quit"`. It may also use this `queue`  to send result back to main thread - because other thread shouldn't access widget (ie. to change text on `Label` or to update `Progressbar`)

Answer (score 0):

although I agree with the handling of treaths with queue I will put an example of how you could do it so you can take a cue from it.
The program starts or stops the thread according to the value of the variable 'check'.

I've start and stop it, see pics.

```
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import ttk
    from tkinter import messagebox
    import threading
    import time
    from datetime import datetime


    class Main(ttk.Frame):

        def __init__(self, parent,):
            super().__init__(name="main")
            
            self.parent = parent
            self.check = True
            self.init_ui()

        def init_ui(self):

            self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)

            w = tk.Frame(self,)
            
            btn = ttk.Button(w, text="Start", )
            btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_start_download)
            btn.pack()

            btn = ttk.Button(w, text="Stop", )
            btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.on_stop_download)
            btn.pack()

            btn = ttk.Button(w, text="Close", )
            btn.bind("<Button-1>", self.parent.on_exit)
            btn.pack()
            
            w.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)

        def on_download(self, evt=None):
            
            while self.check:

                now = datetime.now()
                current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
                print("Downloading current time =", current_time)
                time.sleep(1)

        def on_start_download(self, evt=None):
            self.check = True
            thread = threading.Thread(target=self.on_download)
            thread.start()

        def on_stop_download(self, evt=None):
            self.check = False


    class App(tk.Tk):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            
            self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_exit)
            self.title("Simple App")
            self.minsize(200, 200)

            Main(self,)
                        
        def on_exit(self, evt=None):
            if messagebox.askokcancel(self.title(), "Do you want to quit?", parent=self):
                self.destroy()               
        
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = App()
        app.mainloop()
```

[image]

[image]